# After update NodeJS issue with yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I upated my code to run with NodeJs 18.15. After run it in Jenkins again I get the error:

```
13:21:53  yarn install --prod=false
13:21:53  yarn install v1.22.19
13:21:53  [1/4] Resolving packages...
13:21:53  [2/4] Fetching packages...
13:21:53  npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_AUTH
13:21:53  npm ERR! Invalid auth configuration found: `_auth` must be renamed to `/nexus.local/repository/npmjs/:_auth` in user config
13:21:53  npm ERR! Please run `npm config fix` to repair your configuration.`
```

I change the .yarnrc to:

```
npmRegistryServer: "http://nexus.local/repository/npmjs/:_auth"

unsafeHttpWhitelist:
  - nexus.local
```

But I got the same error. Command `npm config fix` will not change any file.
node 18.15.0
npm is 9.5

Any hint what I missed while update?